# I cannot generate a bar chart from csv file in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning d3.js, and I'm trying to create a bar chart from a .csv file (names of students and their grades). I wrote the code below, but it doesn't generate any bar chart, and I can't understand why. Can you help, please? Thank you!

Here's my .csv file:

Name,Grade
John,95
Jennifer,96
Hank,100
Christina,98
Paul,88
Amy,76
Raul,72
Samantha,70
Sean,68
Abby,90
Sally,85

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


    d3.csv("votiOne.csv", function(data) {

      var canvas = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", 500)
          .attr("height", 500);

      canvas.selectAll("rect")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
              .append("rect")
              .attr("width", function (d) { return d.Grade; })
              .attr("height", 50)
              .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50; })
              .attr("fill", "blue");

    })


  </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse and upload a csv file in D3.js V5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110717/parse-and-upload-a-csv-file-in-d3-js-v5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works depending on the d3 version you are using:

For d3 version 4, the code should work:

```
...
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
...
d3.csv("votiOne.csv", function(data) {
...
```

For d3 version 5, the code is using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (see also this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5)) and looks like this:

```
...
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
...
d3.csv("votiOne.csv").then(function(data) {
...
```

Full working examples:

- [d3js v4 example](https://bl.ocks.org/EE2dev/dc56d5b3b856a24ff27d0f37403f4760)
- [d3js v5 example](https://bl.ocks.org/EE2dev/593a54feb30ceed37cebf12ff6bba057)

Comment: Thank you, ee2Dev!!

Comment: if that solves your question, you can accept the answer.